# pull does not work without specifying schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, mongoose-schema, database-schema

Pull in mongodb does not execute when the array is not defined.

```
const itemsScema = {
  name: String
}

const listSchema = {
  name: String,//list name
  items: []
}
```

Below line of code does not work when items array is not defined as itemsSchema.

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({ name: listName }, { $pull: { items: { _id: checkeditemID} }}).then(result=>{
...
})
```

it works fine when listSchema is modified as:

```
const listSchema = {
  name: String,//list name
  items: [itemsScema]
}
```

Why has providing itemsSchema in items array made it to run and pull to execute?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.